# Python OrderedDict

Tags: python

Один из методов возвращает OrderedDict:

```
OrderedDict([('audio_only', <HLSStream('https://video-weaver.arn03.hls.....')>), 
('160p', <HLSStream('https://video-weaver.arn03.hls.ttvnw.....
```

Как можно получить последний элемент в коллекции? (ссылку?)

Answer (score 1):

```
url = list(ordered_dict.values())[-1].url
```